# How to define a dynamic scope in Ruby Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

I want to search the tracks either by "all of" the filters, or by "any of" the filters. So here is what I got:

**tracks_controller.rb**

```
def search
  if params[:scope] == "any_of"
    Track.search do
      any_of do
        with(:name, "Thriller")
        with(:artist, "Michael Jackson")
      end

      with(:user_id, current_user.id)
    end
  elsif params[:scope] == "all_of"
    Track.search do
      all_of do
        with(:name, "Thriller")
        with(:artist, "Michael Jackson")
      end

      with(:user_id, current_user.id)
    end
end
```

It works as expected. But how to refactor the code to make it DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is Sir:

```
def search
  Track.search do

    mode = (params[:scope] == 'any_of' ? method(:any_of) : method(:all_of)) # don't use method(params[:scope]) for obvious security reason)

    mode.call do
      with(:name, "Thriller")
      with(:artist, "Michael Jackson")
    end

    with(:user_id, current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately Sunspot doesn't support using "any_of"/"all_of" with fulltext search (like `any_of {keywords "bad"; keywords "thriller"}`). I hope the feature will be implemented someday.

Comment: So does this work with facets ? it didnt make any difference to me.
Item.search do |s|  
s.fulltext query  
s.any_of do  
  s.with(:city_id, city_list)  
  s.with(:category_id, category_list)  
end  
end